# How to retrieve function's 'this' object?

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say I have a function object (passed via parameter for example). I want to call the function with parameters stored in an array. This is usually done using `apply()`.

However, `apply()` also requires a `this` argument, which I don't have. Can I somehow get it from the function object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The value of `this` is dependent on how you call the function, it isn't intrinsic to the function.

For this type of situation, I would assume that the `this` object should be `window` (at least if the JS is intended to run in a browser) and make it the responsibility of the calling code to use `bind` (or similar) to work around the loss of the normal `this` value.

Comment: Actually, it's a part of an event binding utility I've written recently, in which I use strings (such as `foo.bar.baz`) to identify callbacks (I need to be able to bind from html and serverside, hence the strings).

However, since I already have logic for resolving the function from the string, I guess I can just pass the functions parent object (ie.   `bar` in the example above) as this. EDIT: if there is a parent object, obviously, otherwise I guess I'll just pass `null` or `false` something...

Answer (score 1):

you can:

a) rewrite the function being passed in to not depend on it's call context

b) call `namespace.func.bind(namespace);` to get a copy of the function with a permanent "this".

I'd suggest option (a). The need for calls to `.bind()` is usually evidence of an antipattern that needs correcting.